# Ignoring `eclipse.refreshLocal` task, which is not available outside of Eclipse

Tags: ant, bamboo

For developers' convenience, all Ant tasks in our codebase feature a `eclipse.refreshLocal` task which tells Eclipse to automagically refresh the workspace after running the Ant task.

This is because too many people have fallen in the trap of not pressing F5 manually to refresh the file system, so that once we discovered the magic task no one will be surely returning to the olf F5-ing.

But now we are deploying Bamboo. I don't want to build separate scripts for Bamboo. I would like Bamboo to just ignore that eclipse.refreshLocal task because it is not run in the same VM as Eclipse.

Any idea on how to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a trick. I am telling my coworkers to:

1. Update their Eclipse Ant runtime and set a custom variable INECLIPSE = true from Eclipse Ant options
2. Add the following to top of all of their `build.xml`s: `xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless"`
3. Use `<eclipse.refreshLocal depth="infinite" resource="/" if:set="INECLIPSE" />` in all Ant tasks
4. Don't bother Bamboo

[Chuck](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/name.michaelrueegg.bamboo.chucknorris) happily said OK to my last build